# undef values in LLVM PHI instructions

Tags: compiler-construction, clang, llvm, llvm-ir

Consider the following LLVM IR snippet.

the value of `%unify.phi` is undefined if the loop body (`while.body9`)  is executed, otherwise it has some specific value (`%c.1` is a defined value).

However when I execute this IR (using `lli`), the value of `%c.2` is always the value of `%c.1`, even if the loop is executed multiple times.

What is the reason for this behavior?  how undefined values are handled in LLVM and is this behavior architecture dependent (depending on how undef is handled in Codegen) ?

[image]

Comment: AIUI, you're seeing that setting a phi to undef keeps the phi's value from the previous iteration, and you're wondering why, and you'd like someone to explain why the code does this instead of... instead of doing something else. Is that it?

Comment: exactly, this was the confusing part. looks like undef is converted to a defined value by early-cse as pointed out in llvm mailing list https://godbolt.org/z/e1M7x5z5K